# jQuery, Cross-Origin request blocked when accesing different jQuery file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this small jQuery script that randomises my div's when the page is refreshed.

```
jQuery(document).ready(
    function ($) {
        jQuery("div.band").randomize("", "div.pickle");
    });
(function ($) {
    $.fn.randomize = function (tree, childElem) {
        return this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            if (tree) $this = $(this).find(tree);
            var unsortedElems = $this.children(childElem);
            var elems = unsortedElems.clone();
            elems.sort(function () {
                return (Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5);
            });
            for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
                unsortedElems.eq(i).replaceWith(elems[i]);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

but when i try to use my collorbox with this script i get a Cross-Origin Request Blocked (Reason: CORS-header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ is missing).

without the jQuery script it works perfect. it also looks like it doesn't send settings to collorbox jQuery file. these files are all on the same server but not in the same maps. i used wordpress for this site.

also this collor-box uses an iframe to render the page, no x-frame protection is on the website's that I'm trying to render.

its using wordpress its own build in jQuery coppy to do this.

Here is a working link for the randomizer [Click me](http://jsbin.com/oyaxa/403/edit?html,js,output)
also here is the link for the jQuery colerbox i use. [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)

This is the code I use to call the collor box in my wp

```
<div class="band">
    <div class="pickle">
        <a class="wp-colorbox-iframe cboxElement" href="www.oldvic.nl">
            <img class="test" src="http://s.wordpress.com/mshots/v1/http%3A%2F%2Foldvic.nl?w=1920" alt="oldvic" /><br />
        </a>
        <header class="upper">
            <h3 class="under">oldvic</h3>
        </header>
    </div>
    <div class="pickle">
        <a class="wp-colorbox-iframe cboxElement" href="www.belder-schoenen.nl">
            <img class="test" src="http://s.wordpress.com/mshots/v1/http%3A%2F%2Fbelder-schoenen.nl?w=1920" alt="belder-schoenen" /><br />
        </a>
        <header class="upper">
            <h3 class="under">belder-schoenen</h3>
        </header>
    </div>
    <div class="pickle">
        <a class="wp-colorbox-iframe cboxElement" href="http://www.soeterboekschoenen.nl/">
            <img class="test" src="http://s.wordpress.com/mshots/v1/http%3A%2F%2Fsoeterboekschoenen.nl/?w=1920" alt="soeterboekschoenen" /><br />
        </a>
        <header class="upper">
            <h3 class="under">soeterboekschoenen</h3>
        </header>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what requests are being made ?

Comment: Where are the requests?

Comment: For better understanding, Please provide a **working demo** (*code snippet,jsfiddle ...*)